# Qualtrics javascript: Display items in pick group rank questiontype in columns

Tags: javascript, rank, qualtrics

I'm working with the Qualtrics "pick, group, rank" question type, but I have a list of 40+ words and I need participants to drag and drop 10 into the box.

Problem is, when you scroll down the page to read the words, the wordbox stays at the top. Is there javascript code that I could add to have the wordbox scroll down as the person reads the words down the list? OR is there a way to list the items in multiple columns instead of one long list?

Comment: hard to help you with only words as reference, no images, no code.

Answer (score 2):

This will work on newer browsers.  Add the following to the bottom of your question text (in html mode):

```
<style>
.Skin .PGR .DragAndDrop .Items ul {
  columns: 2;
  -webkit-columns: 2;
  -moz-columns: 2;
}
</style>
```